# Speech and Gesture Recognition at same time

Tags: c++, kinect, speech-recognition, gesture-recognition

I have created two threads. 1 for speech and 1 for speech.

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadSpeech(LPVOID temp){
speechRecog obj;
obj.start();
return 0;}
DWORD WINAPI ThreadGesture(LPVOID temp){
m_pMR2GestureRec->mainGestureRec();
return 0;
}
```

I am using both codes from other developers. I want to use both of them at a time.
whenever I run threads then only Gesture works and speech kinect can't initialize and generates error of kinect initialization for speech only.

I need help.

Comment: Provide the kinect iniialization code

Comment: //speech initialization 
HRESULT hr = NuiInitialize(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_AUDIO ); 
    if ( FAILED(hr))
    {....}
    hr = InitializeAudioStream();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    { ....} 
    hr = CreateSpeechRecognizer();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {...}
    hr = LoadSpeechGrammar();
    if (FAILED(hr))
     {...}
    hr = StartSpeechRecognition();
    {...}

Comment: //Gesture initialization 
HRESULT  hr;
hr= NuiCreateSensorByIndex(i, &g_hKinectSensor[i]);
g_hKinectSensor[i]->NuiInitialize( NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_COLOR | NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_SKELETON );
if(FAILED(hr))
{...}
g_hNextColorFrameEvent[i] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
hr= g_hKinectSensor[i]->NuiImageStreamOpen(NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_COLOR, NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480, 0, 2, g_hNextColorFrameEvent[i], &g_hColorStreamHandle[i]);
if(FAILED(hr))
{...}

Comment: Given the code you have here, the speech recognition object is local to ThreadSpeech, and will disappear at the end of the function.  You also need to call ::CoInitialize at the start of *each* thread function.

Comment: done both actions suggested by @EricBrown. still, gesture code works fine but speech don't work

Comment: Please edit your question to show *all* the relevant code.   In particular, please show **which line fails, and with what error**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you get the `HRESULT` values which tell you *what* step failed and *why*. Use them; we can't guess.

Comment: I debugged and error is assess denied at hr = InitializeAudioStream();

Comment: But It works fine when I run only speech code. If I run gesture and speech, error appears and hr value is "E_ACCESSDENIED"

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN docs for [`NuiInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/nuiapi.nuiinitialize.aspx) includes the following note:

> If your application supports multiple sensors, use the INuiSensor
>   interface to initialize the sensors instead.

Since you're using both speech and gestures, you'll need to use [`INuiSensor::Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/nuisensor.inuisensor.nuiinitialize.aspx) to separately initialize the speech and gesture engine.